# How do I use forward declared datamembers in a function template? (C++)

Tags: c++, templates

So I have a Class in which I use datamembers of forward declared classes. Now I need a function template for my class but function templates need to be implemented in the header file so I cant acces my members. How can i work around this?

Here is some of my code

```
class Cell;
class Node;


class Wall : public WallAttributes
{
public:
    ///
    virtual ~Wall() {}

private:
    Cell*             m_c1;                ///<
    Cell*             m_c2;                ///<
    Node*             m_n1;                ///<
    Node*             m_n2;                ///<
    unsigned int      m_wall_index;        ///<

private:
    mutable double    m_length;            ///< Length is tracked lazily.
    mutable bool      m_length_dirty;      ///< Marks length dirty.

private:
    friend class cereal::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & archive) const
    {
        archive(m_c1->GetIndex());
        archive(m_c2->GetIndex());
        archive(m_n1->GetIndex());
        archive(m_n2->GetIndex());
        archive(m_wall_index);
        archive(m_length);
        archive(m_length_dirty);
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & archive)
    {
    //Todo
    }

};
```

Which gives the error: Invalid use of incomplete type Cell

Comment: What's the reason you can't have full definitions of `Cell` and `Node`?

Comment: Create a base archive class with pure virtual function to do whatever. Inherit from your archive type with some wrapper class and pointer or instance of the real archive class and pass down at run-time. Now you can create a non-template function which takes a reference to your archive base class.

Comment: @jrok To avoid header bloat? A good technique.

Comment: Since you use members of e.g. `Cell` and `Node`, then you need the full definition of those classes, or the compiler will not know what members they have.

Comment: This is not my code, my task is to make the project serializable so i can't change the structure of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the template definitions to the source file (Wall.cpp).

Change the header to:

```
class Wall : public WallAttributes{
private:
    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & archive) const;

    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & archive);
}
```

On Wall.cpp:

```
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive & archive) const
{
    (...)
}

template<class Archive>
void load(Archive & archive)
{
    (...)
}
```

Since the template functions are private, I am assuming they will only be used in Wall.cpp. But if this is not the case, you may create an intermediate cpp file with the template definitions, like Wall-templates.cpp and include the cpp file in your Wall.cpp.

Comment: They are private, but there is a `friend` declaration just above them. I suspect *that* is from where they're expected to be called.

Comment: Ok, that is why I added the possibility of placing the definitions at "Wall-templates.cpp"

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
class Wall : public WallAttributes {
// ...
private: 
  template<class Archive>
  void load(Archive& archive);
};

// ...

#include "wall.tpp" // templates definitions
```

and then in `wall.tpp`:

```
template<class Archive>
void Wall::load(Archive& archive) {
  // ..
}
```

You can then include headers for `Cell` before `#include "wall.tpp"` or inside that file.

Alternatively you can use this approach instead:

`wall.tpp`:

```
template<>
void Wall::load<Cell>(Cell& archive); // declare template specialization for Cell type
```

`wall.cc`:

```
template<> // define template specialization
void Wall::load(Cell& archive) {
  // ..
}
```

Comment: How does this solve the incomplete definitions issue?

Comment: Right, I fixed my answer to address that.